# PHP sendmail, values not passing through to email

Tags: php, email

I have a contact form on an html page that is using a php script on seperate php page to send text values entered into input boxes in an email

Everything is working except the text entered in the forms input boxes are not passing through, they are blank

Below is what I am doing:

HTML

```
    <form class="form-inline" action="mail_handler.php" method="post"   
     enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="fullwidth">
                  <div class="left-feild col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control color01 background13 border-color08" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control color01 background13 border-color08" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control color01 background13 border-color08" name="number" placeholder="Phone/Cellphone Number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control color01 background13 border-color08" name="company" placeholder="Company name">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="right-feild col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group fullwidth">
                      <textarea class="form-control color01 background13 border-color08" rows="3" placeholder="type your message here" name="message" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submitbutton fullwidth">
                  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn more background07 color01 color01-hover01" >book</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$from = 'From: info@recipient.com'; 
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //email
$subject = 'website booking enquiry';
$message = "From: $name\n Number: $number\n E-Mail: $email\n Company:    
$company\n Message: $message\n ";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers = 'From: info@recipient.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: $email' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header( "Location: index.html" );//if u wish to get redirected
?>
```

Comment: they're blank "when"? When you try it or from your site and somebody doesn't enter anything in it?

Comment: your last header's broken `$headers = 'From:` and voted to close as a typo. It's off-topic.

Comment: Hi Fred -ii- .When I input text and click submit, it only sends the below fields in the email but none of the values that were entered in the input boxes:  From:
 Number:
 E-Mail:
 Company:
 Message:

Comment: Fred -ii-  what do you mean by your second comment?

Comment: It means that `$headers = 'From:` is missing a concatenate/dot. So do `$headers .= 'From:` and your code should (theoretically) work. You should also check for empty fields.

Comment: Thanks.  I am testing the form myself and it still doesn't pass any of the values, I have fixed that error and it still isn't working :( Could it be an issue on the server?

Comment: You're welcome. It's hard to say really. Are you getting the email at all? You should also use `if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email'])) { // process mail }` and you can add to the array in the same fashion (you can replace `||` with `&&` for "and" instead of "or". If that still doesn't work, then I don't know what it could be, sorry Christine.

Comment: Plus, is that your full code? Are you using javascript/ajax with this by any chance?

Comment: and `'Reply-To: $email'` is also failing you here. Read the manual on PHP.net and look at the examples in there http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php or replace it with double quotes `"Reply-To: $email"` since variables don't get parsed in single quotes.

Comment: I posted an answer below Christine. Comments were growing a bit here and was too long to be a comment. I spotted something else also.

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - remove that from your form element.

Comment: @CBroe true, it's not needed. It won't break her code but since she's not dealing with files, it can be safely omitted; good point.

Comment: Sidenote/for the record: I've retracted my close vote since there were more errors than just a missing concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting too long for comments, therefore I have submitted the following.

You have quite a few errors in your code.

You've missed a concatenate/dot for your last header and is "breaking the chain" as it were, and variables don't get parsed in single quotes

Also the first header should not have a leading dot.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$from = 'From: info@recipient.com'; 
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //email
$subject = 'website booking enquiry';
$message = "From: $name\n Number: $number\n E-Mail: $email\n Company:    
$company\n Message: $message\n ";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: info@recipient.com' . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header( "Location: index.html" );//if u wish to get redirected
exit;
```

You should also check for empty fields, because anyone can submit with nothing filled and you will get empty results.

I.e.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email'])) {

// Assign variables to the POST arrays and process mail

$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// ... rest of your code

}
```

Note: `||` means "OR". You can use that, or `&&` which means "AND", or a mix of both.

---

Footnotes:

`\n` will not show the data on separate lines, should that be the goal, since you are using HTML headers.

You will need to use `<br>` if that is what you want to do here.

Consult the manual on mail:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

A few other alternatives to PHP's `mail()`, are PHPMailer and Swiftmailer:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- http://swiftmailer.org/

---

As stated in comments:

> *enctype="multipart/form-data" - remove that from your form element. – CBroe"*

That can be safely removed since you're not dealing with files.

If this is a server issue, then you will need to find out what the problem is and is beyond the scope of the question.